# Bulk/Batch upload of users/groups into Google

Tags: c#, batch-file, google-admin-sdk

I am able to use admin SDK API and using C# standalone code and I am able to implement below operation as well.

Create User, Upadate User, Create Group, Add Membership, remove membership, reset password etc.

However I have a requirement where we need to perform bulk upload of group & users into Google. Please advice if there is any sample code or API which I can use to implement the same.

Regards,
Anurag

Comment: You have to provide your code and any errors you get.  This site is here for getting help with code not asking other people to write code for you.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a solution to bulk user management and you're using .Net or C#, check out my [gShell](https://github.com/squid808/gShell/wiki) project which wraps the APIs with easy-to-use PowerShell cmdlets. Using this you could do something like easily reading a CSV file or calling against an LDAP environment and calling a cmdlet like Get-GAUser or Set-GAUser to make the necessary changes. You'll need to be working on a Windows OS to get the PowerShell working and you'll need some basic PoSh knowledge, but it's [pretty straight forward](https://github.com/squid808/gShell/wiki/Getting-Started) otherwise.

It also has an option to [use the gShell authentication framework in your own .Net project](https://github.com/squid808/gShell/wiki/DotNet-Guide) if you need to customize things a bit more or make an executable.

If you're looking for samples of C# code it's open source so browse away.